# From an expression raised in a power of 2 to an expression raised in the power or 10

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, exponentiation, binary

Is there a simple/"easy" way to convert a big number from a power of $2$ to a power of $10$ equivalent.

Example:
I had $2^{127}\cdot 1.9999999$ which I did the multiplication got the result and from the result I "extracted" the $~1.7\cdot 10^38$

Is there a way for these cases to avoid doing the actual multiplication?

Comment: See my answer to the math StackExchange question [using trial and error in math problems](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863888/using-trial-and-error-in-math-problems), where I show how to use the fact that $2^{10}$ and $10^3$ are nearly equal. See also my discussion under *folding paper* in this [17 January 2008 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6064545).

Answer (score 1):

Take $\log _2\left( x \right)$, then multiply by $\log _{10}\left( 2 \right)$ and the answer is 10^whatever you got.

So $10^{\log _2\left( x \right)\log _{10}\left( 2 \right)}$

Reason:
$\log _b \left( x \right) = \log _b \left( c \right)\log _c \left( x \right) = \frac{{\log _c \left( x \right)}}{{\log _c \left( b \right)}}$

Comment: What is x in my example?

Comment: $2^{127}\cdot 1.9999999$

Comment: Interesting.But I still need a calculator right?So why is this easier than just doing the multiplication?

Comment: I thought you just wanted to avoid multiplying numbers that big, so taking logarithms would make them way smaller and thus nicer to work with.

Comment: I like the approach.It is indeed interesting.My interest is more practical. Convert a big number to the power of 2 to a power of 10 that I can easily understand. I was looking for a "trick" to figure it out roughly (not accurately) avoiding doing the multiplications. +1 though