# A number of bacteria are placed in a glass.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Some amount of bacteria are placed in a glass. One second later each 
bacterium divides in two, the next second each of the resulting bacteria divides 
in two again and again. After one minute the glass is full. When was the glass 
half-full?

Comment: The colony doubles every second so...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using trial and error in math problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863888/using-trial-and-error-in-math-problems)

Comment: Can't believe this has never been asked on Math StackExchange.

Comment: Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429872/a-lily-pad-doubles-in-area-every-second-after-one-minute-it-fills-the-pond-ho/2429893#2429893

Answer (score 0):

Thinking backwards, we can see that if the glass is full after 60 seconds, it must 
have been half full one second before. Answer: after 59 seconds.